# Use of "with" as a preposition

Tags: prepositions

I have learned we can use "with" in a sentence to show any relation or effect with action or quality [Point number #11](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with_1).Then, I have written some sentences.After every sentence, I have also given why I chose "with"  in the sentence.

1. It was a great problem with flood victims.--the problem is related with flood victims.

2.Many students have agreed with the teacher's proposals of planting trees-- these agreements related with the teacher's proposals.

3.around 5000 people have registered with men overnumbering women by 20% --- registration has affected more men than women.

Can anyone help me to rectify my mistakes if there is any.are my explanations right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. It was a great problem with flood victims.**

No problems in the sentence. It either means, depending on the context, that the problem is related to the victims or, more likely, the flood victims are the ones with the problem

**2. Many students have agreed with the teacher's proposals of planting trees**

Yes and yes. The sentence is properly written, and the students think the teacher's proposals are good/should happen

**3. around 5000 people have registered, with men outnumbering women by 20%**

this is correct, but i would add a comma before with (see above) to separate the ideas in the sentence. Your definition is correct too - 20% more men have registered.

Comment: although note, we say "outnumber" not "over number"